# params.get("") is not working when i try to render a page with an id from a local dataset

Tags: reactjs, vite, routeparams, react-routing, urlsearchparams

I'm trying to create a page that renders information dynamically by drawing from a local dataset using params.get(""). While the URL is set, whatever parameter I put in params.get("") does not render on the page.

Here is the code for directing the user to whatever parameter has been set

```
<button onClick={e => nav(`/learn?url=${item.place}`)} className='absolute bottom-5 right-5 text-green-300 bg-[#0F1014] p-2 rounded-sm ease-in-out duration-150 hover:bg-green-900 text-sm'>Learn more</button>
```

Below is the code for the page

````
function Learn() {
    const [params] = useSearchParams();
    console.log(params.get("place"))

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>{params.get("place")}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}```

I tried changing the parameters but it did not help with what I was trying to get done. Any help or advice is much appreciated.
````

Comment: It should be `params.get("url")`, not `params.get("place")`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I tried this but it didn't work